# Skype not listed in Startup Applications

Tags: startup, skype, startup-applications

I checked similar questions and didn't see anybody having the same problem. Skype launches every time on startup. I wanted to stop doing it.

The most obvious solution didn't work in my case, which was to go to Startup Applications and `Remove` it from there. But Skype is not listed in startup apps. I have even set Startup App-s to display hidden applications. So my question is why it is like that? Is it a system bug? How to make Skype displayed there?

My system is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. This is the first system installed on the laptop.

Comment: Actually the most obvious is Skype's settings/preferences. There you can enable/disable running it in the startup.

Comment: Skype settings option is faded out. Maybe the reason is I am not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

MS is too insidious to use the FileStart preferences app, the ~/.config/autostart directory, and even disabling autostart in Skype does not work as of 2023-au-14.

People at https://www.solvetechnow.com/post/how-to-stop-skype-autostart-on-linux identified that MS moved the startup file from ~/.config/autostart to ~/.local/share/applications/skype...  there may be serveral variations, in my case MS Skype had created FOUR (4) variations including skypeforlinux.desktop, skype_skypeforlinux.desktop, ...  plus another TEN (10) copies in snap/skype/289, ... and in /usr/share... and var/lib/snapd ...

In each file in the .config directory I turned the ...AutoStart Enable = from True to False, and then made the file ReadOnly, as recommended, for the four variations in the .config directory and ignored the others and it did the trick.

Cheers

Glad MS continues to harass its users, which drives more people to Linux.

Comment: I have edited only ~/snap/skype/current/.config/autostart/skypeforlinux.desktop, but setting X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false was not enough for me. I also needed to enter a new line Hidden=true.